# How to set height of tableview base on number of row its inserted

Tags: swift, uitableview

Let say I got TableView which got 3 rows.

When I insert record data from DB,it will turn 4 rows.

So,I don't want to see extra row because i set the tableview height.

If my tableView got 4 row,my tableView height is only for 4 rows and not for some extra blank space.

If it turn 3,then height for 3 row.

So,how to make table view height base on number row its inserted.

I am not talking about self-sizing table cell.

I am talking about changing the tableView height dynamically base on the records its inserted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the table view taller within your view controller by changing the framesize, or the layout constraint.

That is, if your table is 3 rows... you can set your table height via it's frame.size.height, or you can adjust a layout constraint (which also can be set to an IBOutlet) to allow more space.

EDIT:

Here is how to do it in code (assuming you are using AutoLayout)

1 ) first add the constraints to your table view

[image: Add Constraints to the Table You want to mess with]

2)

Add the IBOutlet to your view controller code.

[image: Add Outlet to Your View Controller]

3)

Connect the outlet in the storyboard by control clicking on the view controller object and moving the mouse to the bottom edge layout, like this:

[image: Make Connection]

4)

And then now that you have a layout outlet, you can adjust the constant for the bottom edge depending on how tall you want the table to be.

Here, I'm doing it when the view first appears.  You'll need to customize this code depending on your needs.

[image: change layout constraint constant]

Comment: Any Code Help please?Because I am really beginner at setting custom height.And is there anything that I have to do at Storyboard tableView Constraints?

Comment: Ok I will give it a try.Thanks for the help

Comment: Thanks its really worked.Can I get your help with some accordion view : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35394191/making-simple-accordion-tableview-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

Michael solution works like a charm , but I want to add that you can use the height constraint instead of the bottom and in the numberOfRowsInSection function

So you can multiply the row height with the number of rows

My table row height is 40, and the header height is 40

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    var noOfRows = Int()

    if  case == 1 {

          noOfRows = 5

    } else if case == 2  {

          noOfRows = 2

    } 

    heightOfTable.constant = CGFloat(noOfRows) * 40  + 40  // +40 for the header height
    return noOfRows
}
```