# Dynamic Expandable Table View

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Can we implement Expandable `UITableView` having dynamic prototype cell which expands dynamic number of cells inside it? Like:

I have 'x' number of courses in tableView. upon tapping on any course it will expand 'y' number of subjects receptive to that course.

I'm not having any static cell in my tableView. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Refer following link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626028/expandable-tableview-in-iphone

Comment: Make `numberOfSection` to **course.count**, Each section contains one row by default **(i.e)Course Title**.On `didSelect` keep some `BOOL` value depending on that increase the `numberOfRows` on that particular section to the **Subject.count**  and reload the table

Comment: I suggest to use [this library](https://github.com/ujell/YUTableView-Swift), I tried it and it worked fine for me. Also, it does support Swift 3.

Comment: I answer this in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35394191/making-simple-accordion-tableview-in-swift/36138678#36138678

Comment: here you can do it easily in swift https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RKeVv0I3jnA

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ExpyTableView](https://github.com/okhanokbay/ExpyTableView), which makes an expandable section from your given header cell. Compatible down to iOS 8.0.

All you have to do is to import ExpyTableView and then:

```
class ViewController: ExpyTableViewDataSource, ExpyTableViewDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var expandableTableView: ExpyTableView!

  // First, set data source and delegate for your table view.
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 
    expandableTableView.dataSource = self
    //expandableTableView.delegate = self
  }

  // Then return your expandable cell instance from expandingCell data source method.
  func expandableCell(forSection section: Int, inTableView tableView: ExpyTableView) -> UITableViewCell {
    // this cell will be displayed at IndexPath with section: section and row 0
  }
}
```

You can see your former table view section is now an expandable table view section. You can also download the example project and see more detailed examples.

In the example project, there is a specific example which fit your needs. You just have to add this code:

```
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return x //x is your provided number here.(e.g. number of courses)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return y //y is your provided number here.(number of subjects related to a course)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple and complete code for expandable tableview cells I use

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
struct Data {
    var title = ""
    var categories = [String]()
    var isSelected = false

    init(title: String, categories: [String]) {
        self.title = title
        self.categories = categories
    }
}


var tableData = [Data]()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    tableData.append(Data(title: "Click Me", categories: ["Row 1", "Row 2", "Row 3"]));
    tableData.append(Data(title: "Click Me", categories: ["Row 1", "Row 2", "Row 3"]));
    tableData.append(Data(title: "Click Me", categories: ["Row 1", "Row 2", "Row 3"]));
    tableData.append(Data(title: "Click Me", categories: ["Row 1", "Row 2", "Row 3"]));


    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 3
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let viewHeader = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, 50))
    viewHeader.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10, 0, self.view.frame.width - 10, 50))
    titleLabel.text = tableData[section].title
    viewHeader.addSubview(titleLabel)


    let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, 50))
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.headerDidSelect(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    btn.tag = section
    viewHeader.addSubview(btn)

    return viewHeader
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableData[section].isSelected ? tableData[section].categories.count : 0
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = tableData[indexPath.section].categories[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}


func headerDidSelect(sender: UIButton) {
    for i in 0..<tableData.count {
        if tableData[i].isSelected == true {
            tableData[i].isSelected = false
            tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: i), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            if  i == sender.tag {
                return
            }
            break
        }
    }
    tableData[sender.tag].isSelected = true
    tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: sender.tag), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
}
```