# Collapse cells of a section in UICollectionView swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, accordion, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView with multiple sections. Each section has a HeaderView (of type UICollectionReusableView) and multiple cells (of type UICollectionViewCell).

Each header will have a hide/show button which will hide/show the cells. At any point of time the header will not go invisible even if all the cells under it are collapsed/hidden.

```
+------------------------+
| A Header     [HIDE]    |
| [Cell A]     [Cell B]  |
| [Cell c]     [Cell D]  |
| -----------------------|
| B Header     [HIDE]    |
| [Cell A]     [Cell B]  |
| [Cell c]     [Cell D]  |
|                        |
+------------------------+
```

If clicked on Hide button of "A Header" the design will look like:

```
+------------------------+
| A Header     [SHOW]    |
| -----------------------|
| B Header     [HIDE]    |
| [Cell A]     [Cell B]  |
| [Cell c]     [Cell D]  |
+------------------------+
```

I read about Accordion Menu but it seems to be used with TableView. [Making Simple Accordion TableView in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35394191/making-simple-accordion-tableview-in-swift)

I also tried reloading 0 number of cells to replicate the hiding behavior

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    isFirstHidden = true
    collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
        let indexSet = IndexSet(integer: 0)
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        collectionView.reloadSections(indexSet)
    }, completion: nil)
}

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if (section == 1 && isFirstHidden) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 4;
}
```

but I still get NSInternalInconsistencyException - Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 1.

Can you please give me any pointers or share the link of a documentation which will help me understand how collapse behavior of cells work.

EDIT:
One more example of what I want to achieve.

```
+------------------------+
| A Header     [HIDE]    |
| [Cell A]     [Cell B]  |
| [Cell c]     [Cell D]  |
| -----------------------|
| B Header     [HIDE]    |
| [Cell A]     [Cell B]  |
| [Cell c]     [Cell D]  |
| -----------------------|
| C Header     [HIDE]    |
| [Cell A]     [Cell B]  |
| [Cell c]     [Cell D]  |
|                        |
+------------------------+
```

If Hide button of Header B is clicked -

```
+------------------------+
| A Header     [HIDE]    |
| [Cell A]     [Cell B]  |
| [Cell c]     [Cell D]  |
| -----------------------|
| B Header     [SHOW]    |
| -----------------------|
| C Header     [HIDE]    |
| [Cell A]     [Cell B]  |
| [Cell c]     [Cell D]  |
|                        |
+------------------------+
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking for `section == 0 && isFirstHidden` not `section == 1`? In your example `Section 0` will have `0` items and `Section 1` will have 4 items (after hiding `Section 0`). Sections are 0-based not 1-based.

Comment: Hey! I am aware of the fact that sections are 0 based. I want to hide the cells of section 1 and not section 0. Whenever I try to hide the elements of section 1 by returning 0, the app crashes. However, if I do the same for section 0, no exception is thrown and the display is as expected. I will edit the question by adding one more example

Comment: Your additional example is better but your code still reloads section 0 when you use `IndexSet(integer: 0)`. I have written similar code in the past and I've just reviewed it. When I toggle the section closed I use `self.collectionView?.deleteItems(at:)` (and pass all the `IndexPath`s of the items to remove) and when I toggle the section open I use `self.collectionView?.reloadSections()` (and pass all the sections in an `IndexSet`) rather than using `reloadSections()` for both adding and deleting items.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add datasource method.In that method you can design your header or footer view.

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

        case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:

            let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: "Header", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionReusableView
            let headerBtn = UIButton()
            headerBtn.addTarget(self, action:#selector(headerBtnTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
            self.view.addSubview(headerBtn)

            return headerView

        case UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter:
            let footerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: "Footer", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionReusableView

            return footerView

        default:

            assert(false, "Unexpected element kind")
        }
    }
```

In header view, `headerBtnTapped` method will call after pressed headerBtn on headerView.So you can toggle the array or content(which you return on `numberOfItemsInSection`) in `headerBtnTapped` method and reload it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is not what I am looking for. My issue is with the method - numberOfItemsInSection, and not with how to trigger a method when the user taps.