# How to show/hide a label by pressing a label in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, label, tableview, cell

How to show/hide a label by pressing a label in swift?

how to show/hide a button by pressing a button in swift?

how to show/hide a cell by pressing a cell in swift?

thank you.

Comment: From what you've described, it sounds like you want an accordion menu. Possible duplicate of [Making Simple Accordion TableView in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35394191/making-simple-accordion-tableview-in-swift)

Comment: Show your tried code.

Comment: I think I need to Identify the tableviewcontroller to the cocoa file at first, but when I do that, my static cells (I have made them manually in storyboard) disappears completely - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

**For the button:**
Create an outlet action for the button. In the method type:
'yourButton'.isHidden = true

**For the label**
Add a tap gesture recognizer to the label. In the acition for it, type:
'yourLabel'.isHidden = true

**For the cell**
I don't think it is the way to go. It is better if you follow iOS standards, and delete the row by swiping to the left. Like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: 
UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   if editingStyle == .delete {
      self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!

I'm pretty new to swift, and now I have another problem. I need to use the show/hide in a tableviewcontroller. I'm using static cells and have named the cells manually in storyboard. but when I identify the tableviewcontroller to a cocoa tableview file, my static cells are disappearing, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: No problem at all - hope that helped :) 
What do you need to use show/hide in the tableView? I would use the tableView delegate methods like numberOfRows, numberOfSections and cellForRow to determine which cells to show at a given time :)

Comment: My tableviewcontroller is the first screen when you open the app. Then I have a lot of cells which is like the menu, but I think its to much for one screen, which is why I would like to press cell1 which shows cell2, cell3 and cell4, and then when pressed cell2, the screen2 opens - I'm danish, sorry for my english, I hope it makes sense. :)

I'm not sure I know have the delegate methods works? :)

Comment: I'm also danish ;)
If you are using it as a menu, then maybe have a look at tapbar menu instead. If you want to, you can have my email, phone number or something? Then I could help you better maybe. also in danish :)

Comment: okay, thank you, that would be a big help, I would like your email then please? :)

Answer (score 1):

UILabel will need a gesture recognizer to process a tap:

```
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:")
label1.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .Ended {
        label2.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

UIButtons will just need to be hooked up to an IBAction in the storyboard:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ object:AnyObject)
{
   button2.isHidden = true
}
```

Cells cannot be hidden or shown, must be added or removed. Override:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   // add or remove items from data source, then
   tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I need to know how I identify my tableviewcontroller to a cocoa file?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean. You will typically subclass UITableViewController in Xcode (New > File... > Cocoa Touch Class > Class 'MyTableVIewController' (Subclass of: UITableViewController, Language: Swift) ... Drag a UITableViewController into your storyboard file and set Custom Class Name in right hand storyboard Inspector view for that controller. Note when you create the class file, the most common override functions are added for you. It seems overwhelming at first, but you'll get it pretty quick.

Comment: that is what I mean, thank you, but I have already tried that after I have made static cells in storyboard (without coding) and then when I run the app, all my static cells dissapears, and I don't know why?

Comment: With static cells, you probably don't need a subclass, but with a subclass, check the 'numberOfSections' and 'numberOfRowsInSection' functions. They should return the number of static sections and static rows in your storyboard.