# UITableView : Nested Section Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, sections, expandable-table

I am trying to implement a UITableView with the following structure :

```
struct DataArray {
    var mainsection : String
    var titlecontent : String
    var contentsection : [(question : String, answer : String)] = [(String, String)]()
}

var dataArray = [DataArrayArray]()

dataArray = [DataArray(mainsection : "Section 1","Section Title 1",[("question1","answer1"),("question2","answer2")]), 
DataArray(mainsection : "Section 2","Section Title 2",[("question1","answer1"),("question2","answer2")])]
```

The TableView should look like this and when the user clicks Section 1 ->expand the subsection (SectionTitle1 & SectionTitle2); when user clicks SectionTitle1 -> expand the subsection(Question1 & Question 2); When the user again clicks Question1 -> show the answer :

**Section 1**

- Section Title 1

  - Question 1

    - Answer 1
  - Question 2

    - Answer 2

**Section 2**

- Section Title 1

  - Question 1

    - Answer 1
  - Question 2

    - Answer 2

Can anyone help me with this or any other solution to solve this?

Comment: Unrelated but don't name a custom struct `Data`. It could interfere with the struct `Data` in Foundation

Comment: You can design your cell to be expanded or collapsed on taps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of TableView is generally called *Accordion TableView*. If you run google search for this you will find a lot of tutorials and sample codes. 2 links are mentioned below

1. [Making Simple Accordion TableView in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35394191/making-simple-accordion-tableview-in-swift)
2. https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-how-to-build-a-table-view-with-collapsible-sections-96badf3387d0

Comment: Thank you for the reference and it works. @ibnetariq